# How to coy/paste from mac to ubuntu shell?

Tags: ubuntu, mac, vmware

I am running Ubuntu inside VMware on Mac (Big Sur). I am trying to copy/paste commands from mac to Ubuntu shell using all possible options e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, but nothing seems to work, including pasting from menu after right clicking on the shell. Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: Have you installed (or reinstalled) VMware Tools on the Ubuntu machine?   I just did copy / paste from Windows 10 to my VMware Ubuntu VM and it worked fine

Comment: VMware tools are required to share the clipboard between the computers. And also make sure that you're not remapping any related keys in the VMware settings